# Footnotes for a table

Tags: tables, floats, footnotes

My question is so simple and straightforward. How to make footnote for an element of a table?

```
  \begin{table}
  \centering

  \label{priority list}
  \begin{footnotesize}
  \begin{tabular}{|l||l||l|}
  \hline
   & sample 1& sample 2  \\
     \hline\hline
 Results\footnote{please put me underneath of this table} & &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{table}
```

Comment: It would be so much simpler and more straightforward if you posted a complete minimal example we could compile rather than a mere fragment of code.

Comment: @cfr sorry about that. Was in rush and forgot the MWE.

Comment: It should be noted that the problem is trying to create a float (footnote) inside another float (table), not the tabular format.  Putting the tabular inside a minipage also works (footnotes stay inside minipages).

Comment: @JohnKormylo what is a minipage?

Comment: `\begin{minipage}{<width of minipage>} <stuff> \end{minipage}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**threeparttable** or **threeparttablex** are one option. The standard default would be to use `\footnotetext` and `\footnotemark` but these packages can make things easier.

The use of **booktabs** and reading the advice on typesetting professional quality tables is also recommended.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Priority List}\label{tab:priority list}
      \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \toprule
        & sample 1& sample 2  \\
        \midrule
        Results\tnote{a} & &  \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[a]please put me underneath of this table
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

## EDIT

You can change the font within the `tablenotes` environment. For example,

```
  \begin{tablenotes}\tiny
    \item[a]please put me underneath of this table
  \end{tablenotes}
```

[image: tiny note]

You can also get an enhanced set of facilities by loading **threeparttablex** which is an extended version of **threeparttable**. Although primarily designed to work with `longtable`, it can also enhance the standard `threeparttable` environment. See the documentation for details.

Comment: is this possible to set font size to the footnote too?

Comment: Please see edit.